# Excel Random number from a set of options

Tags: excel-formula

In *MS Excel*, how can I randomly sum up to a target number with numbers divisible by 5?

For example, I would like a completely random output of numbers divisible by 5 (5,10,15,20….) in cells B1:B100, to add up to 10000.

I initially looked at the `CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN)` option but I can't get up to make the numbers add up to 10000.

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed? Do the random numbers need to be uniformly distributed?

Comment: If the min number is 0, what is the max number allowed? Do you have an idea which logic this could be based on? I don't think that a formula can achieve this. You will need to use something else. If `VBA` is an option, add the `vba` tag right below your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Office 365, `B1` enter the formula:

```
=LET(
rndArr,RANDARRAY(100,1),
Correction,INT(SEQUENCE(100,1,1,-1/100)),
INT(rndArr/SUM(rndArr)*2000)*5+IF(Correction=1,10000-SUM(INT(rndArr/SUM(rndArr)*2000)*5),0))
```

EDIT: the below added in response to the comment about constraining it to a min/max. It's not actually foolproof for all min/max values, but seemed to work well enough for me with the values you supplied.

```
=LET(
Total, 10000,
Min, 10, Max, 300,
rndArr, RANDARRAY(100, 1),
Correction, SEQUENCE(100, 1, 1, 1) = MATCH(MIN(rndArr), rndArr, 0),
rndArr5, INT(rndArr/SUM(rndArr)*Total/5)*5,
rndArrMinMax, IFS(rndArr5 < Min, Min, rndArr5 > Max, Max, TRUE, rndArr5),
rndArrMinMax + (Total-SUM(rndArrMinMax)) * Correction
)
```

Explanation of what that does:

- Enter Total, Min and Max variables
- create `rndArr`, an array of random numbers (that is the correct size, 100 rows x 1 col)
- create `Correction`, a boolean array of the same size as `rndArr` where the only TRUE value is the position of the smallest value in `rndArr`. This is because we'll need to add a figure in later to ensure the total is correct, and want to add it to the smallest number in the array (best possible chance that it won't go above our maximum, remember I said this wasn't foolproof for all values).
- create `rndArr5`, which proportionately increases rndArr so it totals 2000, rounds down to nearest integers, then multiplies by 5. The result is an array of random multiples of 5 that totals somewhere below 10000
- create `rndArrMinMax` by checking `rndArr5` (our progress so far) against desired min and max values, editing any outside of our desired range to be the min or max value respectively.
- Final output value is that corrected value, plus any difference to make the correct total (that's `Total - SUM(rndArrMinMax)`, which is multiplied by our `Correction` boolean array so it only gets added on the smallest value in the array. Again, this may result in that smallest value going over the max if the totals are way out and/or the Max is very small, but there's not much you can do about that with random numbers.

Comment: Wow, this is much more complex than I imagined. It's brilliant. Thank you so much! Also, is there a way to set minimum/maximum numbers as well in addition to the formula above? (i.e. minimum 10 & max 300)

Comment: It's possible, just adds more complexity - I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is just perfect for my needs. Thanks so much for your kind explanation as well! Really appreciate it.